# I cannot solve error #2136 swf contains invalid data

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

So, still working on my Tamagotchi style game and am using seperate classes and, upon advice from here, am avoiding nesting functions if I can!
However, I wrote some code to add/remove food depending on `hitTestObject` conditions and they were working fine when in the main class.
As soon as I moved everything out to a `Food Class`I got the above error.
I have tried using traces and commenting things out ... I am stumped.
It is kind of frustrating because, as a learner, I just feel like I am starting to crack this and *WHAM* I hit a wall and it reminds me that I actually know nothing.

Anyway, I would appreciate some advice.
Here is my code for the two classes.
Thanks, Again!

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import DraggableItem;
import Food;    

public class Tamagotchi extends MovieClip {

    const BG_SPEED:int = 10;
    const BG_MINX:int = -270;
    const BG_MAXX:int = 0;
    const BG_MINY:int = -200;
    const BG_MAXY:int = 0;

    var bG:BackGround = new BackGround();   

    var home:Home = new Home();
    var soph:SophRun = new SophRun();
    var item:DraggableItem=new DraggableItem();
    var food:Food = new Food();


    public function Tamagotchi() {      

    addChildAt(bG, 0);      

    bG.addChild(home);
    home.x = 850;
    home.y = 80;

    addChild(soph);
    trace("HI");
    soph.x = 350;
    soph.y = 250;
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressListener);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bgScroll);        
    }

    public function keyPressListener(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (e.keyCode == 65)
        {
            soph.x -=  5;
            soph.scaleX = 1;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 68)
        {
            soph.x +=  5;
            soph.scaleX = -1;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 87)
        {
            soph.y -=  5;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 83)
        {
            soph.y +=  5;
        }
    }//End of KeyPressListener

    public function bgScroll(e:Event)
    {
        if (soph.x > 550 && bG.x > BG_MINX)
        {
            bG.x -=  BG_SPEED;
            soph.x -=2;
        }
        else if (soph.x < 150 && bG.x < BG_MAXX)
        {
            bG.x +=  BG_SPEED;
            soph.x +=2;
        }
        else if (soph.y > 400 && bG.y > BG_MINY)
        {
            bG.y -=  BG_SPEED;
            soph.y -=2;
        }
        else if (soph.y < 400 && bG.y < BG_MAXY)
        {
            bG.y +=  BG_SPEED;
            soph.y +=2;
        }
    }//End of bgScroll

} //End of Class
```

} //End of Package

And this is the `Food Class` ...

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import Tamagotchi;

public class Food extends MovieClip{


    var food1:Food1 = new Food1();
    var food2:Food2 = new Food2();
    var food3:Food1 = new Food1();
    var food4:Food2 = new Food2();

    var foodArray:Array = new Array(food1, food2, food3, food4);

    var foodButton:FoodButton = new FoodButton();
    var tam:Tamagotchi = new Tamagotchi();

    public function Food() {

    addChild(foodButton);
    foodButton.x = 150;
    foodButton.y = 650;

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, addingFood);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eatFood);
    }

    public function addButton(xpos:int, ypos:int)
        {           
            addChild(foodButton);
            foodButton.x = xpos;
            foodButton.y = ypos;            
        }

    public function addTheFood()
            {   
                for (var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {           
                        addChild(foodArray[i]);
                        foodArray[i].x = 900 * Math.random();
                        foodArray[i].y = 650 * Math.random();           
                    }
            }

    public function addingFood(e:Event)
        {
            if (tam.soph.hitTestObject(foodButton))
                {       
                    addTheFood();   
                    removeChild(foodButton);
                    addButton(900 * Math.random(), 650 * Math.random());
                }
        }

    public function eatFood(e:Event)
        {
            for (var j:int = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    if (tam.soph.hitTestObject(foodArray[j]))
                        {
                            removeChild(foodArray[j]);
                            foodArray[j].x=100000;                              
                            trace("Food gone!");
                        }                       
                }
        }

}//End of Class
```

}//End of Package

Sorry to keep pestering you guys, but I am determined to get to grips with this and you lot seem to really know your stuff, so I am just trying to learn!
Be gentle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Tamagotchi Class you have

```
 var food:Food = new Food();
```

And in your Food Class you have

```
var tam:Tamagotchi = new Tamagotchi();
```

This seems rather infinite loopy...
(One gets created, which creates the other, which creates the first one again, which creates the other again, and so on...)

Comment: Agree with Karma.  
You need to re-think the structure of your program. It doesn't make sense for `Tamagotchi` to manage `Food` objects or visa-versa.  
You need something 'above' them that will manage all instances of `Tamagotchi`(s) and `Food`(s), e.g. the concept of a 'world' where these objects exist.

Comment: Karma - Thank you. :D

@DFreeman - Thank you for the advice. I'll get on that. 

Thanks to both of you, advice like this really helps and gives me hope I will grasp this ... hopefully!